# Ionic: background geolocation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, maps, cordova-plugins

I'm using Ionic & Firebase to create an Android application for geolocation. I used `ngCordova.geolocation` and I successfully get the device current location.

My problem is that I need to continuously get current location, as long as the user doesn't turn off geolocation and callback a function every time the geolocation change, and test if the user is inside one of many circles in the maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using the ngcordova.geolocation plugin, it has a method to keep tracking the device position via [watchPosition](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/#watchpositionoptions). There's an example in the docs indicating how to use it:

```
  var watchOptions = {
    timeout : 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
  };

  var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
  watch.then(
    null,
    function(err) {
      // error
    },
    function(position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude

      /* Further code to execute on each update */
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @radyz, one more thing, how to lunch a function if GPS is turned off while watchposition activated?

Comment: launch a function?

Comment: launch* I mean start a treatment*